# Can't Install lessc using NPM on mac

Tags: node.js, npm, less

I was trying to install lessc globally on my mac, I installed node.js from their website, and when I run the command (npm install -g less) I get this, could you please help me, all I want to do is to install Less and get the less2css compiler on sublimetext 3 work properly:

```
npm install -g less
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock' }
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mohammad/npm-debug.log
MacBook-Pro:~ Mohammad$ npm install -g less
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/Mohammad/.npm/_locks/less-c2213c903e2e7354.lock' }
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mohammad/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute this command as superuser if you do not have write permissions on the `/usr/local` directory.

Please try:

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped :)